# if $f'(x)<2f(x)$ and $f(\frac{1}{2})=1$ find the interval in which $\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f(x)dx$ lies

Tags: calculus, integration, integral-inequality

if $f'(x)<2f(x)$ and $f(\frac{1}{2})=1$ and $f$ is a function from $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ to $\mathbb R$  find the  interval  in which $\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f(x)dx$ lies, given $f(x)$ is non-negative .

My attempt:-

from $f'(x)<2f(x)$
we have,

$$f(x)<e^{2x} +C$$

substituting the  value of $f(\frac{1}{2})$ we get

$$1-e <C$$

integrating $f(x)<e^{2x} +C$ between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$

we get

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f(x) < 2e(e-1)+\frac{C}{2}$$
to find the upper limit one can substitute C to obtain

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f(x)< 2e(e-1)+\frac{1-e}{2}$$

As $f(x)$ is non-negative, the minimum value of $C$ is $e^2$ is $-e^2$
so

$$e^2-2e<\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f(x)dx< 2e(e-1)+\frac{1-e}{2}$$

however, my book says that the answer is $(0, \frac{e-1}{2})$

I'm not sure I understand where I'm going wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The lower bound is equal $0$ as the integrals  $f_n(x)={(3-2x)^n\over 2^n}$ tend to $0.$ There a mistake in your calculations: the antiderivative of $e^{2x}$ is equal ${1\over 2}e^{2x}.$

Comment: you have to multiply c not add it. because you have taken antilog

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, got it. Thanks!

Comment: @ShlokJain, thanks !